# Discretization of 2D PDE on a non-trivial domain

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

#### Setup

The 1D convection-diffusion equation is given by:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + v \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - \mu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 0
\end{equation}
where $u$ is the solution variable, $v$ is the convection velocity, and $\mu$ is the viscosity coefficient.

1. Spatial Discretization:
   Define cell averages:
   $$
   U_i = \frac{1}{dx} \int_{x_{i-1/2}}^{x_{i+1/2}} u(x, t) \, dx
   $$
   where $x_{i-1/2}$ and $x_{i+1/2}$ are the left and right boundaries of cell $i$.
2. Time Integration:
   Use a first-order upwind scheme for convection and centered differences for diffusion:
   $$
   \frac{U_i^{n+1} - U_i^n}{\Delta t} + v \frac{U_i^n - U_{i-1}^n}{dx} - \mu \frac{U_{i+1}^n - 2U_i^n + U_{i-1}^n}{dx^2} = 0
   $$
3. Solve for $U_i^{n+1}$:
   $$
   U_i^{n+1} = U_i^n - v \frac{\Delta t}{dx} (U_i^n - U_{i-1}^n) + \mu \frac{\Delta t}{dx^2} (U_{i+1}^n - 2U_i^n + U_{i-1}^n)
   $$

#### Question

I want a similar numerical scheme for 2D convection-diffusion equation that is given as follows
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + v \nabla_{\textbf{x}} u - \mu\Delta u = 0, \quad \textbf{x} = (x,y)^T \in \Omega, \ \ t \in \mathbb{R}^{+}, \ \ v \text{ constant vector}$$
Where the domain is a region between two non-concentric circles (but the smaller one lies inside another) and the boundary and inital conditions:
\begin{align*}
    &u(\textbf{x}, t) = 0, \quad \textbf{x} \in \partial\Omega, \ \ t \in \mathbb{R}^+ \\
    &u(\textbf{x}, 0) = u_0(\textbf{x}), \quad \textbf{x} \in \Omega
\end{align*}

I have triangulated the domain (see the figure below).

If I want to discretize the equation (cell-centered discretization), I will need to find the weak form of the problem by integrating over each controll volume (triangle) $A_i$ and use
$$\frac{1}{|A_i|}\int_{A_i} v\nabla_{\textbf x} u d\textbf x = \frac{1}{|A_i|}\oint_{\partial A_i} (v\cdot n)u d\textbf s$$
and
$$\frac{1}{|A_i|}\int_{A_i} \mu\Delta u d\textbf x = \frac{\mu}{|A_i|}\oint_{\partial A_i} \nabla u\cdot n d\textbf s$$
For the time dependent term, we can still use the approach from 1D case $$\frac{\partial u_{i}^n}{\partial t} \approx \frac{U_{i}^{n+1} - U_{i}^{n}}{\Delta t}$$

However, I am not sure how to efficiently discretize the other integrals. At least, it doesn't seem as simple as the 1D case.

Any help (continuation of my try, another approach, comments with hints and reference materials that discuss the same type of problems) is greatly appreciated.

---

> Cross-posted<sup>[[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)]</sup> the question on [SciComp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/43483/fvm-for-non-regular-domain-with-triangular-mesh) Stack Exchange. However, it feels like deriving the numerical scheme is closer to calculus (pure math perspective) which I could then use to tailor that question by asking a concrete implementation related issues in MATLAB.

Comment: Looking up "finite volume methods" will give you enough information. Depending on the relation between $|v|$ and the diffusion $\mu$, you may also need to look for "stabilization methods" and "upwinding".

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes, it is indeed the finite volume method. The reason why I am asking this question anyway is that most of the online resources are too simplified (1D or a simple domain) or too generalized which is a bit harder to grasp and implement as a newcomer to the subject. The discussion here on this topic with this (almost) concrete example would be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The finite element works well enough here. Using the simplest time discretization, at each time step you need to solve the problem
$$
u^{n+1} = u^n + \delta t(\mu \Delta u^{n+1} - v \cdot \nabla u^{n+1})
$$
or
$$
\delta t \mu \Delta u^{n+1}- \delta t v\cdot \nabla u^{n+1}-u^{n+1} = u^n
$$

Multiplying by a test function $w \in H^1_0(\Omega)$, and integrating by parts when necessary, you get to
$$
-\delta t \mu \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla w-\delta t\int_{\omega}v \cdot u^{n+1} w - \int_{\omega} u^{n+1} w  = \int_{\omega} u^n w 
$$

Introducing a finite element space with some basis $\{\varphi_1, \cdots , \varphi_N\}$, this will just amount to the solution of a linear system. The numerical integration on each triangle will add to approximate the integral over $\Omega$. Below you can find an example with $\mu = 1$, $v = (1,1)$, $\delta t =0.1$ and $u(x,y,0)=xy$. The figures represent the mesh, the initial condition and the solution at time $t=1$, respectively.

[image]

[image]
[image]

---

```
Uncurated Freefem++ code for this example:

    // Parametrization of the boundary
border a(t=0,2*pi){x = 3*cos(t); y= 3*sin(t);};
border b(t=0,2*pi){x = -1.5+cos(t); y= -sin(t);};

//Building the mesh
mesh Xh = buildmesh(a(100)+b(50));


//Building the finite element space, in this case P2 elements
fespace Vh(Xh,P2);

Vh u, w, uold;

real dt = 0.1, mu = 0.01, v1 = 1, v2 = 1;
int i;

u =x*y;

//plot(Xh,ps="0.eps",wait=true,fill=true);

// defining the problem to be solved in every time step
problem adv(u,w)
    = int2d(Xh)(
        -dt*mu*dx(u)*dx(w)-dt*mu*dy(u)*dy(w)
    ) 
    - int2d(Xh)(
        dt*v1*dx(u)*w+ dt*v2*dy(u)*w
    )
    - int2d(Xh)(
     u*w
    )
    - int2d(Xh)(
        uold*w
    ) + on(a,u=0) + on(b,u=0);

// Time loop
for(i=1; i<=10;i++){
    uold = u;
    adv;
    //plot(u,ps=i+".eps",fill=true);
}

plot(u);
```

Comment: Thank you! The reason I was trying finite volume is that I messed up the implementation of FEM last time :D What software did you use here?

Comment: I used Freefem++, i can post the code if you want.

Comment: Yes, would be great to see the code as well! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @VIVID I added the code.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please suggest any student friendly book or any material to learn FDM, FVM and FEM with 1D and 2D examples (if you have any in mind)? Because I need to learn FVM for convection-diffusion with time too. Once again, thank you for your effort here.

Comment: Leveque has great books on FDM and FVM. It has been a while since I looked, but I believe they derive some 2D schemes.